# C# code re-use public class Foo<T> method parameters

Tags: c#, types, constructor, code-reuse

I was hoping someone could help me with a problem. I am attempting to make a new class of Type:

```
public class Foo<T>
```

whose only method's job is to iterate through another classes' properties. There are about 20 classes with a varying amount of properties defined:

```
public class Bar {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Shirt {
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}

public class Pants {
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Waist { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
    public string Inseam { get; set; }
}
```

And public class Foo's method is:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public string FooMethod(T before, T after /* other variables? */) {
        // compare before & after
    }
}
```

Each class that is named the same is going to go into `Foo`'s primary method twice, but with different property values. So `Bar` *before's Id & Name* could be `1 & "Bar"` while `Bar` *after's Id & Name* could be `2 & "BarBar"`.

From here, other operations are going to be done to compare each property in *before & after*. However, since the number of properties in each class varies, and I am only looking to use one method I have a dilemma.

Comment: You use word "constructor" so often, and yet you have no constructors. Do you mean to use "property" instead of "constructor"?

Comment: Yes, my wording is off, thanks for clarifying and for the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want in your FooMethod to compare object of multiple types, you can override Equals and GetHashcode methods in all your classes(Bar, Shirt, Pants ...), and do comparison there. That way your FooMethod will only call `before.Equals(after)` to compare them.